# Calling a post web api method using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a web method like the following

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostDeviceControl(DeviceAccessRequest deviceAccessRequest)
    {

        var deviceAccessResponse = new DeviceAccessResponse(deviceAccessRequest.RequestId)
            {
                Status = "OK"
            };
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<DeviceAccessResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, deviceAccessResponse);
        return response;
    }
```

This is how I'm consuming it from a C# application, and it works great

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55208/");

            var request = new DeviceAccessRequest
            {
                RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                DeviceId = "ACU/B2/01/R1",
                AccessType ="Unlock",
                LoginId = "tester",
                Password = "tester" ,                    
            };
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accesspanel", request).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var deviceAccessResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DeviceAccessResponse>().Result;

            }
        }
```

This is my jquery snippet

```
var request = {
    RequestId: "123",
    DeviceId: "ACU/B2/01/R1",
    AccessType: "Unlock",
    LoginId: "tester",
    Password: "tester"
};
alert(JSON.stringify(request));
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:55208/api/accesspanel',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
    }
});
```

I have set a breakpoint in my web api method, but it doesn't break. and the error portion of my ajax() gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you accessing the web page using the URL: http://localhost:55208 ?

Comment: looks like same origin policy issue, check the browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: Yes I am able to access the web page URL http://localhost:55208/api/accesspanel, only that if I were to browse that URL in browser, it says The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Comment: I agree with @ArunPJohny - are you running api/accesspanel from the same site that your javascript is called from?

Comment: Also, you said you're error function is getting called.  What's being output?  Anything helpful there?

Comment: I'm running the JQuery code from a different project than my web API project. I do not have chess to my source code at the moment, and I'll post the error message as soon as I can,but from what I can remember, the alert I got was [error, error] error, or [object, object] error

Comment: @PapyrusBit if these are two different projects and they are hosted in different domains/ports most probably it is a same origin policy violation error, the error message will be clear in your browser console using chrome developer toolbar/firebug

Comment: Yes the error is access control allow origin

Comment: How should I overcome this?

Comment: There are 2 errors. First is 405 method not allowed. Second is the origin error

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Relaxing_the_same-origin_policy for solutions (FYI, localhost:80 and localhost:81 are considered different origin)

Comment: Not tested out by myself yet, but looks like this post could help you out for enabling CORS: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201211/Blog/Using-CORS-With-ASP-NET-Web-API/